# Java Graph Dijkstras Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

So I am trying to implement a graph in Java and I can do BFS and DFS but I am having some issues with my Dijkstras algorithm. Basically here's my graph...

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAVwW.png)

So when I run the Dijkstras algorithm, I get the following results

```
Shortest path cost between ST A: -1, Path: [ST, B, A]
Shortest path cost between ST B: -1, Path: [ST, B]
Shortest path cost between ST C: -1, Path: [ST, B, D, C]
Shortest path cost between ST D: -1, Path: [ST, B, D]
Shortest path cost between ST M: -1, Path: [None]
Shortest path cost between ST ST: 0, Path: []
```

The results should be...

```
Shortest path cost between ST A: 10, Path: [ST, B, A]
Shortest path cost between ST B: 6, Path: [ST, B]
Shortest path cost between ST C: 12, Path: [ST, B, A, C]
Shortest path cost between ST D: 9, Path: [ST, B, D]
Shortest path cost between ST M: -1, Path: [None]
Shortest path cost between ST ST: 0, Path: [ST]
```

As you can see, I am unable to get the path cost and for ST to C I'm getting ST, B, D, C instead of ST, B, A, C which is the shorter path.

My method takes in a start node, end node and an arraylist for shortest path. Attached below...

```
private boolean alpha;
private int temp;

public int doDijkstras(String startVertex, String endVertex,
        ArrayList<String> shortestPath) {

    if (!dataMap.containsKey(startVertex) || !dataMap.containsKey(endVertex)
            || getAdjacentVertices(startVertex) == null
            || getAdjacentVertices(endVertex) == null) {
        shortestPath.add("None");
        return -1;
    }
    if (startVertex.equals(endVertex)) {
        return 0;
    }

    ArrayList<String> currentPath = new ArrayList<String>();
    Stack<Node> visited = new Stack<Node>();

    Node currentNode;
    Node previousNode = new Node();

    int lowestPath = -1;

    currentNode = new Node(startVertex);
    visited.push(currentNode);
    currentPath.add(currentNode.name);

    while (visited.size() != 0) {
        alpha = false;
        djAux(startVertex, endVertex, previousNode, currentNode, visited,
                shortestPath, currentPath, lowestPath);
        previousNode = visited.peek();
        visited.pop();
        currentPath.clear();
        if (visited.size() != 0) {
            visited.peek().previous.add(previousNode.name);
            currentNode = visited.peek();

            for (Node n : visited) {
                currentPath.add(n.name);
            }
            temp = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < currentPath.size() - 2; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < currentPath.size() - 1; j++) {
                    temp += getCost(currentPath.get(i), currentPath.get(j));
                }
            }
        }
    }
            Object[] shortPath = shortestPath.toArray();
    int totalDistance = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < shortPath.length; i++) {
        if (i + 1 == shortPath.length) {
            break;
        }
        totalDistance += getCost((String) shortPath[i],
                (String) shortPath[i + 1]);
    }

    return totalDistance;
}
```

I also have a helper method...

```
    private void djAux(String startVertex, String endVertex, Node previousNode,
        Node currentNode, Stack<Node> visited,
        ArrayList<String> shortestPath, ArrayList<String> currentPath,
        int lowestPath) {

    Object[] map = getAdjacentVertices(currentNode.name).keySet().toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        if (!currentPath.contains(map[i])
                && !currentNode.previous.contains(map[i])) {
            currentNode = new Node((String) map[i]);
            temp += getCost(visited.peek().name, currentNode.name);
            visited.push(currentNode);
            currentPath.add(currentNode.name);
            djAux(startVertex, endVertex, previousNode, currentNode,
                    visited, shortestPath, currentPath, lowestPath);
        } else if (i == map.length - 1) {
            if (shortestPath.size() == 0) {
                shortestPath.add("None");
                temp = -1;
            }
        }

    }

    if (currentNode.name.equals(endVertex)) {
        if ((lowestPath > 0 && temp < lowestPath && temp != -1)
                || lowestPath < 0) {
            shortestPath.clear();
            lowestPath = new Integer(temp);
            alpha = true;
            for (String s : currentPath) {
                shortestPath.add(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the node class

```
    public static class Node {
    ArrayList<String> previous;
    String name;

    public Node() {
        name = null;
        previous = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        previous = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

Here is the getCost() method

```
    public int getCost(String startVertexName, String endVertexName) {
    if (!getAdjacentVertices(startVertexName).containsKey(endVertexName)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return getAdjacentVertices(startVertexName).get(endVertexName);

}
```

I tried debugging this but could not find why some values weren't printing out.

Can someone help?

Thank you in advance.

Edits: I figured out how to update the cost. see above.

Comment: nobody knows what `getCost` does ...

Comment: Its now included

Comment: it's still incomplete...`getAdjacentVertices` does what? and I can't see any method where you keep track of the costs between nodes. And using the same variable `temp` in different methods is also not the method idea I think

Comment: I can't just put the whole project here. But getAdjacentVertices returns a Map<String, Integer> which contains neighbor nodes of a particular node